# Remove item at index

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my iCarousel, I use this to remove the items at index:

```
NSInteger index2 = carousel2.currentItemIndex;
[carousel2 removeItemAtIndex:index2 animated:YES];
[items2 removeObjectAtIndex:index2];
```

So the image in the view of the specific index is remove.

But I don't know how to reduce the count in my array to 1 or reduce the index count. How to do it?
sorry for the bad english.

Comment: The array count automatically reduces when you call removeObjectAtIndex

Comment: I want to put it in my condition, because my code doesn't seem to know it.

Comment: I can't understand what you want? Can you please post some more code or update the question?

Comment: I just want to have a code like this: `items2.count - 1;` but can't seem to make it work in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove any object from NSMutableArray the length of array automatically reduced by 1. You can check length of array by using

```
[carousel2 count];
```

and

```
[items2 count];
```

Comment: After I remove an index then log it, it still has the same number.

Comment: log the array and check that is the object is properly removed or not.

Comment: I log it, it was remove from the view. But when I log it, still the same count.

Comment: I try say that to log the whole array like NSLog(@"Array: %@",carousel2); then you can find out removeObjectAtIndex method works properly or not.

Comment: Its okay now. What i need is to let my app know that I'm removing an app. so I want to counter it, like this: ` items.count - 1;` or something. but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can store items.count to a int variable and check array length with that int variable to make sure that any objects are removing from array or not.

Comment: How to counter it by reducing?

Comment: suppose initially int itemLenth=items.count;.....if any object reduced from items array items.count will be reduced by 1 and itemLenth> items.count.

Comment: I want to reduce it programmatically, like setting its index count programmatically

Comment: You can not set array length programmatically. array length depends on the number of the objects in the array.

Comment: i mean counter it. like for example i++. but I want to reduce it to only 1.

Comment: Oh, hi again, the count was reducing, but when I log the array it doesn't reduce,

Comment: that mean removeObjectAtIndex does not work...create a method which will remove object... loop through the array and don't add that object which you want to remove.

Answer (score -1):

I did not get so much idea from your question. but I think you have to reload iCarousel after remove item.

Comment: What i need is to let my app know that I'm removing an app. so I want to counter it, like this: ` items.count - 1;` or something. but it doesn't work.